# Android highchart how to disable export button?

Tags: android, highcharts

I want to disable the export button from the chart. I tried the below [code](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-android/issues/2#issuecomment-371075562).

```
HIChartView chartView = (HIChartView) findViewById(R.id.chartView);
chartView.options = new HIOptions();
chartView.options.exporting = new HIExporting();
chartView.options.exporting.enabled = false;
```

But it doesn't seem to work out.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The options should be assigned to the chart at the very end.

Example:

```
HIOptions options = new HIOptions();
HIExporting exporting = new HIExporting();
exporting.setEnabled(false);
options.setExporting(exporting);
chartView.setOptions(options);
```